# fedora linux --- compiling first linux module

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, fedora

Getting error while compiling my first kernel module in Fedora linux.

Source code :--

```c
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
static int __init hello_start(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}
module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Makefile :----

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

error at make time :--

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64/build M=/home/dinesh/development/linux/kernel_modules/hello modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Now if i see build is there or not , i get following o/p. Build is shown as an softlink :---

```
$ ls -l /lib/modules/3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64/
total 2632
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     38 Apr 15 21:32 build -> /usr/src/kernels/3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x.
```

**[I got same error even after installing, kernel-devel :--](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/6/html/Release_Notes/ar01s07s07.html)**

My makefile is correct it have correct tab before rule. Please suggest how to resolve this error ?

Comment: Does `/usr/src/kernels/3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64` exist?

Comment: Only these two folders exist ----> /usr/src/kernels/3.8.7-201.fc18.x86_64 --- & --- /usr/src/kernels/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64 ----> softlink one does not exist

Comment: you probably need the corresponding `kernel-source` package installed.

Comment: @Katoch Are you able to build the kernel source?

Comment: How can i install corresponding kernel-source package .. ? please suggest the procedure ?

Comment: Please suggest i am new to this. Any help will be appreciable ?

Comment: @Peter How to build the kernel source (as i do not have source for the exact kernel which is running on my PC) ? What is the need to build kernel source ?

Comment: @Katoch I was suggesting to build the kernel source because you could build a custom kernel with your module within the source tree.  Note that you want your module to match the kernel version.  You could also build and install your custom kernel.  Since this is Fedora, you could use the rpm tool to retrieve and install the kernel source package.  See this wiki: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel

Comment: @peter as per the link suggested by you we can get the kernel source by following topic -- Get the Source --- then after following this process it will install source of my kernel here --- ${HOME}/rpmbuild/SOURCES ---- after this copy source to following path --- /usr/src/kernels/3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64  --- have i got it right ?

Comment: @Katoch That sounds about right.  Note that this is the Linux kernel as Red Hat has configured it.  You can also get the kernel directly from kernel.org and mirrors.  All versions are available.  Many/most people will put the kernel source in /usr/src/linux or make that a symbolic link to the source.  This all may seem like a round about way to build/load your first module, but module developers need to be familiar with the kernel and how their module works with it.

Comment: @Katoch Also, be sure not to overwrite any files that are already in /usr/src/linux.

Comment: You do NOT need a kernel source tree to build modules in fedora; you just need to match the `kernel-devel` and `kernel` packages versions of the kernel you are building against.

Answer (score 3):

As guido said, you have to match your current kernel and the kernel-devel package.

To get your kernel version run

```
uname -r
```

I get 3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64, download that kernel-devel version

```
sudo yum install kernel-devel-3.6.10-4.fc18
```

Or update your system and boot with the new kernel, I believe those two will automatically match.